# Uwamp 3.1.0 says apache port 80 is busy while it seems not

Tags: apache, port80, uwamp

Uwamp 3.1.0 refuses to start apache on port 80 arguing that this port is already in use.

This is quite strange because :

- tcpview tool shows no process using port 80
- my old easyphp v12 runs perfectly on apache port 80.

Is it a bug or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the port to 8080 to test. then let me know if that then starts the server. Also try changing the PHP Version one lower or one higher and then try again using port 80.

Answer (score 0):

1) Check if you have an installation of IIS on your machine (if you have C:\inetpub, you have IIS too)
If you don't use it, you can uninstall it.

2) If not, you can also change the Apache port to the 8080.
a) In the following file : 
UwAmp\bin\apache\conf\httpd_uwamp.conf
Change this line :

By this one :

b) Restart Uwamp

c) Go to : http://localhost:8080/

Normaly the UwAmp's homepage appears.